# JQuery droppable and large table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to optimize response time on a page with a "large" table that is a jquery droppable that accepts ~6 draggables. Like others I've seen poor response time when making each of the  droppables. I've read both [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552951/how-can-i-make-my-jquery-draggable-droppable-code-faster) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302354/jquery-optimizing-droppable-on-mouseover), but I can't seem to get my code to work.

My basic problem is I don't know how to get a reference to the  element in which the draggable was dropped. It seems the only element I can get access to is the actual draggable.

Here's how I've defined my jquery code:

```
$( "#grid table" ).droppable({
                    //disabled: 'true',
                    //activate: function (event, ui) {
                    //          console.log("Activated table")
                    //},
                    //over: function (event, ui) {
                      //      console.log("Dragged over")
                    //},
                    //activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                    //hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                    tolerance: 'pointer',
                    drop: function( event, ui ) {
                            console.log("draggable DROPPED!!!");
                            //$( this ).animate({ backgroundColor: ui.draggable.attr("colorValue") }, 250);
                            var cell = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft(), event.pageY - $(window).scrollTop());

                            console.log('Dropped cell is'+cell);
                            console.log(ui.position)
                            console.log(ui.offset)
                            console.log(document.elementFromPoint(ui.position.left, ui.position.top))
                            $(cell).animate({ backgroundColor: ui.draggable.attr("colorValue") }, 250);

                            console.log('Setting background to:'+ui.draggable.attr("colorValue"));  
                    }
```

Any help you can provide is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) in  drop: function( event, ui ) refers to the element in which the draggable was dropped

Comment: Right but in this case since the droppable is set on the <table> tag, this refers to the table. I need to locate the specific <td> on which the draggable was dropped.

Comment: From quick look I see two ways - set each td as droppable or calculate td position

Comment: Setting each td as droppable is a big performance bottle neck. I was trying to calculate the td position in my code above by using document.elementFromPoint but that's returning the img tag that's draggable instead of the td. How would you recommend locating the td?

Comment: Here is solution for tolerance: pointer, when drop event fired calc cell position under mouse pointer - http://jsfiddle.net/HdqbZ/3/

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I was wondering how to do. I appreciate the help.