# Possible draggable/droppable performance bug with thousands of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

After mouse release, droppable drop callback is called after ~2.5s, later on ~90ms. This I think can be optimized when droppable greedy is false. Earlier jQuery UI versions, such as 1.9.2, perform at constant ~120ms. Tested only on latest Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/6DLSw/3/

```
Open up your browser console and hit run.
Then try dragging the red square somewhere and drop it by releasing the mouse.
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Any suggestions how to quickly optimize without downgrading?

Comment: You should limit the number of active draggables and droppables using the `mouseover` event. Link to a similar question + answer - [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302354/jquery-optimizing-droppable-on-mouseover)

On a separate note, using jQuery to append a large number of raw HTML table elements to the DOM increases the loading time. It's also not a good practice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6DLSw/5/ try dragging this slowly. I don't think it's possible to actually add droppables if the drag helper is visible. Mouseover/mouseenter/nor any other event is actually registered while dragging slowly - the mouse is always on the same element. I could try global mousemove, but the best heuristic algorithm on the actual use case I could come up takes ~10ms, which is way too long on every mousemove event. The same algorithm can be applied after drop with one big droppable, which is what I'm trying to do. There's only several draggables, they have no significance.